# Assert.Inconclusive failed

Tags: selenium, automation

I have a basic Automation script which was failing with below error message when trying the run the script.

Error Message:

**Assert.Inconclusive failed. There was a problem communicating with the WebDriver, if this problem persists please contact support**

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
1)  Open IE
2)  Open Internet Option
3)  Click on Security Tab
4)  Ensure the “Enable Protected Mode” is same for all 4 Zones (Either Check or Unchecked, But should be same)
5)  Save the changes and run your script
```